# How do I make an internal link with CKEditor?

Tags: 8, navigation, wysiwyg

I am using Drupal 8.

Using the standard WYSIWYG editor, when I click on the link button, I only get the option to add a url. I would have thought there would be some capabilities to look up existing pages.

Is there some way to create an internal link?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, what you're looking for is covered by the [LinkIt project](https://www.drupal.org/project/linkit).

> Linkit provides an easy interface for internal and external linking
>   with wysiwyg editors by using an autocomplete field. Linkit has by
>   default support for nodes, users, taxonomy terms, files, comments and
>   basic support for all types of entities that defines a canonical link
>   template.

Once you install the module, you'll need to create a profile (under **Administration > Configuration > Content authoring > Linkit**) for selecting your entities. Following that, configure your text format (under **Administration > Configuration > Content authoring > Text formats and editors**) to use your LinkIt profile.

Once associated, you should be able to add a LinkIt button to your text format toolbar which will let you autocomplete links to your page content.

Answer (score 1):

> I would have thought there would be some capabilities to look up
>   existing pages.

You need to install [CKEditor Entity Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor_entity_link) OR go with the other answer which has more features.

> [image]